# ring and module problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $$F=\mathbb{R}$$ $$V=\mathbb{R}^{4}$$ consider two matrices
$$S1=\begin{vmatrix} 
 0&-1&  0& 0\\ 
 1&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& -1\\ 
 0&0  & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}  ,  
S2=\begin{vmatrix}
 0&-0&  -1& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1\\ 
 1&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&-1  & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}$$
and put $S$={$S1$,$S2$}
  $$ \forall(\neq 0) v\in V $$ ,
$$ S,V \notin Fv$$
show that {$V,S1V,S2V,S1S2V$} is linearly independent over $F$ in $V$.
I can't understand solved by division ring. I need some your help. please

Comment: "*I can't understand solved by division ring.*" This doesn't make any sense in English. Do you mean that you want to prove that the span of these four things make a division ring?

Comment: I also notice you have a $-0$ in $S_2$ and that $S_2$ looks suspeciously asymmetrical. Can you please check $S_2$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've got miss problem, just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the four matrices $I=\begin{vmatrix} 
 1&0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  1&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  1& 0\\ 
 0&0  & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix},S_1=\begin{vmatrix} 
 0&-1&  0& 0\\ 
 1&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& -1\\ 
 0&0  & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}$ and 
$  
\\S_2=\begin{vmatrix}
 0& 0&  -1& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1\\ 
 1&  0&  0& 0\\ 
 0&-1  & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix},S_1S_2=\begin{vmatrix} 
 0&0&  0& -1\\ 
 0&  0&  -1& 0\\ 
 0&  1&  0& 0\\ 
 1 & 0  & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}$.

It's easy to verify that $S_1^2=S_2^2=(S_1S_2)^2=S_1S_2(S_1S_2)=-I$. This suggests we should map $S_1\mapsto 1$, $S_2\mapsto i$, $S_1S_2\mapsto k$ from the $\Bbb R$-span of these matrices into the quaternions $\Bbb H$, and verify that this mapping is an isomorphism. This way, we've shown that the ring formed by the span of these matrices is just a copy of Hamilton's quaternions $\Bbb H$, which is a division ring.

---

Notes:

*"Show that $\{V,S1V,S2V,S1S2V\}$ is linearly independent over $F$ in $V$*": I guess you have just not carefully written what you mean. A set of vectors can be linearly independent or not, but you haven't written a set of vectors, you've written a set of four sets of vectors. It would make sense to say "show $\{I,S_1,S_2,S_1S_2\}$ is a linearly independent set".

The following part is also very confused:

*put $S$={$S1$,$S2$} $ \forall(\neq 0) v\in V $ ,$ S,V \notin Fv$*

Perhaps if you elaborate more in your comments or your post, I can offer more help on that part too.